# Columnsep affect line breaks in a twocolumn paper

Tags: line-breaking, tex-core, two-column

With the following code, TeX break lines after every two `\mybox`s, which is what I want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[a3paper,landscape,twocolumn,columnsep=6cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\makebox[0.5\linewidth][l]{#1}\allowbreak\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\mybox{AAAA}
\mybox{BBBB}
\mybox{CCCC}
\mybox{DDDD}

\lipsum[2]
\mybox{AAAA}
\mybox{BBBB}
\mybox{CCCC}
\mybox{DDDD}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I change `geometry` settings from

```
\RequirePackage[a3paper,landscape,twocolumn,columnsep=6cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
```

to the following line

```
\RequirePackage[a3paper,landscape,twocolumn,columnsep=4cm,left=5cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
```

Even if `linewidth` is the same, TeX changes its line breaking.

[image]

What is the problem with it? And how to improve `\mybox` command to get correct result with different `columnsep`?

Comment: In the second case, `\linewidth` is 27970197sp, but twice half the `\linewidth` is computed as 27970196sp. One scaled point can make the difference. You get an underfull `\hbox` also if you do `\hbox to 2in{\hskip1in\hskip1in}` for precisely the same 1sp difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just being hit by rounding error,

```
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\makebox[0.5\linewidth][l]{#1}\allowbreak\hfill\ignorespaces}
```

works where the extra glue should be 0pt but....